# Is using Length more efficient than using === as stopping criterion?

Tags: function-construction, core-language, functional-style, built-in-symbols

I am using

```
NestWhileList[
  f[#, elems]&, 
  pairs, 
  Length[#1]<Length[#2]&, 
  2, Infinity, -1
 ]
```

to generate all *suitable* subsets from `pairs` of `elems`;

`f` takes a list of subsets of length `n` and combines it with `elems` in order to pick *appropriate* subsets of length `n+1`. The process continues until the `Length` of the generated subsets doesn't change.

(*note*: each subset is of `Length` `n`-it is what `Subsets[elems, {n}]` would return if you could supply an additional function to select *admissible* subsets according to given criteria)

**My question has to do with selecting an efficient stopping criterion.**

If I am not mistaken, using `NestWhileList` with the same arguments and replacing the test with `UnsameQ` is equivalent to using `FixedPointList`.

If lists are somehow aware of their `Length` then using a criterion using lengths of successive lists may be efficient instead of checking for `===`;

however that may not be the case if testing for `===` is somehow aware of the structure of the `FullForm` of the expressions and '*sameness*' is equally efficiently evaluated.

So, the question is if **using `Length` is more efficient than using `===`**, in the context of the discussion above.

Comment: Can't you just... you know... try it? :) I think a timing comparison of trying the two approaches would be much more substantial than people on this site arguing about it, no?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer sure, I did actually time it; on my limited test cases `Length` was a winner by a small margin; I was hopping there was a consensus on the issue since my function generates lists that get big really fast; any possible efficiency gains are welcome; issues that may be slowing down code are not visible at first glance (eg `PackedArrays` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)) and simply timing it doesn't always settle it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it *is* faster to use comparison by `Length` instead of `UnsameQ`, in particular, when two lists indeed coincide. (If the list do not coincide, methods like comparing few bits or hashing may provide an inexpensive test with a high probability of short-circuit.) Indeed, the internal data structures behind `List` contain a field that stores their `Length`; so `Length[a] == Length[b]` is an $O(1)$ operation. But comparison of whole lists of length $n$ should be $O(n)$ operations. Here is a timing experiment that illustrates what I said:

```
n = 10000000;
a = RandomSample[Range[1, n], n];
b = a;
b[[1]] = b[[1]];

a === b // RepeatedTiming
Length[a] == Length[b] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.010, True}
>
> {5.3*10^-7, True}

You might wonder why I used `b[[1]] = b[[1]];` above. If I hadn't used it, `SameQ` would be at least as fast as the `Length` method! The reason is that due to *lazy copying*, the execution of `b = a;` itself will never kick off a copy operation. Instead, the pointer in the `MTensor` belonging to `b` in the C++-backend is simply set to the pointer of the `MTensor` of `a`. So `SameQ` has only to compare their pointers without even touching the memory that stores the actual values of the lists. Hence in this case, `SameQ` boils down to comparing of a single (long unsigned) integer, thus an $O(1)$ operation.

But `b[[1]] = b[[1]];` *manipulates* `b` so that a separate copy has to be made in storage. Now the `MTensor` of `b` points to another memory location. Hence, `SameQ` has really to access all the memory for the entries of `a` and `b` which is obviously an $O(n)$ operation.

### Hint

Never ever use `a == {}` in order to test whether a list `a` is empty. Because with `a` from above, we have:

```
a == {} // RepeatedTiming
a === {} // RepeatedTiming
Length[a] == 0 // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.42, False}
>
> {1.8*10^-7, False}
>
> {3.5*10^-7, False}